# What are the locations of the various theme files in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, themes

Where are the locations of the various theme files stored in Windows 7?

In specific, system as well as per-user theme files.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Regional themes (Country themes):

```
%SystemRoot%\Globalization\MCT
```

Installed themes (Aero, etc):

```
%SystemRoot%\Resources\Themes
```

Per-user installed themes (including pre-installed from OEM):

```
%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Themes
```

Current wallpaper file (if any):

```
%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Themes
```

Answer (score 6):

User installed themes are located on `%AppData%\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Themes`; in Windows 7 they are on `%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Themes`

Comment: This isn't a valid path, at least on Windows 7

Comment: @FactorMystic It is on my Windows 7:  `C:\Users\<logon>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Themes`

Answer (score 1):

Some of the Wallpapers for the default Aero Themes are stored here as well:

```
%SystemRoot%\Web\Wallpaper
```

Comment: I tried to find where flowers theme and this answer is the best for me on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

When I have a quick look on Vista, they're under

```
C:\Windows\Resources\Themes
```

are they still there under Win7?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in Windows 7 theme files are (just like Vista) stored in:

```
%SystemRoot%\Resources\Themes
```