# Location of wallpapers used in various Windows 7 themes

Tags: windows-7, themes, desktop-customization

Where can I find the various pictures of each theme in Windows 7? I know where all the regional themes are, but I do not know where the Architectural, Character, and Landscape theme pictures are.

I want to take all the pictures, move them to a folder in "pictures", and use every single one of the pictures as a theme slide show for my desktop background.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the locations of the various theme files in Windows 7?](http://superuser.com/questions/18076/what-are-the-locations-of-the-various-theme-files-in-windows-7)

Comment: @soandos Not the same case. This is one step deeper, examining the theme files.

Comment: @iglvzx, Your answer is basically the same as the accepted answer to the question I posted.

Comment: @soandos The **.theme** and **.msstyle** files are located in `%SystemRoot%\Resources\Themes` but the wallpapers are not. This question is specifically about said wallpapers.

Comment: @iglvzx, the .theme files can be unpacked to give the pictures, but I see your point.

Comment: @soandos Not with Windows 7, atleast. The .theme files are simply configuration files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at the **.theme** files in `%SystemRoot%\Resources\Themes`, you can find the wallpaper referenced under `[Control Panel\Desktop]`. The root folder for these wallpapers is: `%SystemRoot%\Web\Wallpaper\`.

Note: `%SystemRoot%\` will generally be `C:\Windows\`.

Comment: %SystemRoot%\Web\Wallpaper\   Thank you very much. This is what I was looking for. I have been searching everywhere, but I was always told to go to the MCT file or to "search on google." You are the first helpful person. :D

Comment: @soandos , iglvzx was more accurate because this was a quicker method. Unpacking and all that actually would take longer and it is more complicated for me. By the way, do I need to close this question now? Or do I just leave it as is?

Comment: Aj, you do not need to close the question. Welcome to Super User!